# append icon to download links but not if it is an image

Tags: jquery, append

Using the following code I want to add an icon to the text link but not to the image link. and I want the image in-line rather than as a background as the usual css background image method doesn't work for link text that wraps lines.

```
<a href="foobar.pdf"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/100/abstract/1" /></a>
<br />
<a href="foobar.pdf">Title of the PDF (10MB)</a>
```

I need to do this with jQuery as I manage a large site (over 4 million pages).

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var non_img_link = $("a:not(:has(img))");
var icon = $("<img>", {src: "icon.png"});

non_img_link.append(icon);
// or .prepend() if you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a:not(:has(img))') // gets all anchors that do not contain an image.
```

Using the above selector you can append what is needed to anchors that do not contain an image.